# How to prove a sequence is strictly increasing and bounded above?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction, recurrence-relations

For this proof, I'm not sure if I am doing it right. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence defined recursively by

$a_1 = \sqrt{6}$
$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{6+5a_n}, n = 1,2,3,...$

Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing and strictly bounded above

$a_2 = \sqrt{6+5\sqrt{6}}< \sqrt{6+5*15} = 9$

$a_3 = \sqrt{6+5a_2}$

$a_3 = \sqrt{6+5\sqrt{6+5 \sqrt{6}}}$

wts there exists an M st $a_n \le M$

Choose $M = 9$

Base Case: $a_1 = \sqrt{6}<\sqrt{81} = 9$

Induction step:
Let k in the natural numbers be arbitrary

Assume $a_k \le 9$

$a_{k+1} = \sqrt{6+5a_k} < \sqrt{6+75} = \sqrt{81} = 9$

Therefore by induction, $a_n \le 9$

$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{6+5a_n}$

$a_{n+2} = \sqrt{6+5a_{n+1}}$

$a_{n+1} \le a_{n+2}$

Therefore, the sequence is strictly increasing and strictly bounded above

Comment: I don't understand your calculation.  You appear to assert that $a_2=5\sqrt 6$ but this is not true.

Comment: its root 6 plus five times root 6

Comment: Your formula for $a_3$ incorrectly replaces $a_2$ with $5\sqrt 6$.

Comment: Check the edit I made.

Comment: I changed it, take a look

Comment: the formula for $a_3$ is correct now.  But I don't see how you are arguing that the sequence is increasing.  Basically, you just assert it with no argument.  Worth noting:  the sequence is, in fact, bounded by $6$.  Worth proving that.

Comment: Ok, but is my induction correct? If not, how can I fix it?

Comment: The $75$ appearance is a bit odd, I would say instead $a_{k+1}=\sqrt{6+5a_k}\le\sqrt{6+45}=\sqrt{51}<\sqrt{81}=9$

Comment: Well, it is hard to follow.  You incorrectly  assert that $a_{k+1}=\sqrt {6+a_k}$ to start and then you write $75$ for no apparent reason.  But I think if you clean it up it should be good.

Comment: Ok, but we are still showing that $a_n \le 9$ right?

Comment: @zwim why did we pick $\le sqrt{6+45}$?

Comment: If $a_k\le 9$ then $6+5a_k\le 6+5\times 9=6+45$

Comment: @zwim I see, so just fix that and then my induction proof would be correct?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct globally, but I think you are not expressing yourself clearly about why the sequence is strictly increasing. The base case is $a_1<a_2$, which is clearly true. Andn, if $a_n<a_{n+1}$, then $6+5a_n<6+5a_{n+1}$ and therefore $\sqrt{6+5a_n}<\sqrt{6+5a_{n+1}}$. But this means that $a_{n+1}<a_{n+2}$.

Comment: Since that is true, doesn't it mean it's strictly increasing?

Comment: @dg123 Yes, it is strictly increasing. I was commenting your proof, not the statement itself.

Comment: So what is wrong with my proof?

Comment: @dg123 First: you did not mention that $a_1<a_2$. Second: you didn't justify the equality $a_{n+1}\leqslant a_{n+2}$.

Comment: But we can conclude the equality by intuition though, can't we?

Comment: @dg123 If intuition is enough for you, then you don't need proofs, right?

Comment: Is my induction proof right at least?

Comment: @dg123 Yes, it is.